# Download a folder to internal storage and list the folder items in separate listview

Tags: java, android, file, listview

**In my application,  I want to download the folder and store to internal storage,That folder contains sample.text, sample.jpg, sample.pdf and sample.mp4. 
 I want to store each file type into a particular folder. For example, .text files go to the text folder.**

> My question was

- How to download the folder
- How to list the folder items in separate listview like (***sample.text file go to textList,sample.pdf go to pdfList etc..***)

***Please help me!!***

Answer (score 0):

Its simple get the file extension then use a switch statement and store specific file in specific folder.

```
String ext= getFileExtension(String fileUrl)
{
case ".jpg" :
storeFile("D:/Images");
break;
.
.
.
.
.//and so on
}
```

Comment: @Vijaykumar is there any problem in the answer